# List and model synchronizing

Tags: javascript, rendering, sapui5

I am curious about how UI5 rendering engine works - how it synchronizes view and model. For example if there is a sorted list and 1 object is changed in the model of this list, how does SAPUI5 know it should update only the one list item and not the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely your question

Do you want to know how DOM is renderized in SAPUI?

SAPUI is a MVC framework. In your case these items are Model (data from DB). If there is a change in Model you should make a request for seeing these changes.

Dou you want that component HTML List detect automatically your changes in DB and refresh your view? I think it's a little complicated to make

Comment: Sorry if I haven't asked the question clearly enough. My question is about how the SAPUI5 rendering engine works. For example when I change 1 object of a list of 1000 objects - how does SAPUI5 change only that one object insted of rerendering the whole list.

Comment: Sorry for responding later. SAPUI is built with JQuery. So,behavior of SAPUI components is similar to JQuery controls.